# Charging Macbook Air With 5V 2.4A Power Bank

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

I recently bought a X-Dragon 500,000mAH Solar Charger (Input: 5V 2A, Output: 5V 2.4A) for me to use on camping trips.  I plug it in via the USB-C cable and nothing seems to happen.

Is there hardware or an adapter that will charge my 2021 Macbook Air?

Answer (score 0):

The specifications show it should work, so you may need to charge it up fully from the wall to validate that when it’s charged, it puts out USB PD. Are you able to get a detailed power level and then shut down the Mac and let it charge for an hour and recheck?

[Solar charging isn’t generally ideal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/7660/5472) for portable computers.

- X-Dragon 500,000mAH Solar Charger

[On amazon, this product says it’s only for emergency use](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S2B2M1D), and not for routing charging in general. It seems more designed for phones than computers.

> charging is designed for emergencies, not a primary source of charging due to the compact solar panel size and sunlight intensity, it takes long time to charge under sunlight, so we highly recommend charge the solar charger via an adapter or computer, which only take a about 9.5 hours.

So it’s asking you to charge it from your Mac, not the other way around. You should still see some charge, power off your mac, let it charge for an hour and check the level, but it might just be you don’t have enough sunlight. I would have the manufacturer validate yours is functioning properly if you have concerns it’s not what you need. I would use [your charger for iPhones and iPads (in a pinch)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/276078/5472).

Answer (score -2):

The answer is, that the power bank is not capable of charging your MacBook Air.  The MacBook Air needs at least 3A to charge, and the power bank provides at most 2.4A.  In other words, you need a power bank with a higher output, if you want to be able to charge your MacBook.

As is, the MacBook will draw 3A, which will overload the power bank, and the power bank will provide a very low voltage, which is too low to be able to charge your MacBook Air.

Comment: Don't make stuff up. Devices don't randomly start drawing 3A unless the power bank signals 3A support using resistors on the data lines.